# How to get info about the neighboring cells using 3G networks

Tags: android

i'm trying to get info about the nearby neighboring cells. it's correct using 2G networks,but i get '-1' for lac and cid.

Is there anything i can do to make it work on 3G networks?

```
infoList = new ArrayList<CellInfo>();
CellInfo cellInfo = null;
List<NeighboringCellInfo> infos = tm.getNeighboringCellInfo();
for(NeighboringCellInfo info : infos){
    cellInfo  = new CellInfo();
    cellInfo.setType(1);
    cellInfo.setNetworkType(info.getNetworkType());
    cellInfo.setCi(info.getCid() + "");
    cellInfo.setLac(info.getLac() + "");
    cellInfo.setRssi(info.getRssi() );
    cellInfo.setPsc(info.getPsc()+"");
    infoList.add(cellInfo);
    cellInfo = null;
}
```